# CL option (policy?) to extract Developer ID Installation

Tags: bash, macos, code-signing-certificate

I currently dynamically extract the Developer ID Application from the keychain using

$ security find-identity -p codesigning

This does not work for Developer ID Installer.

Does anybody have a solution? I hate to hardcode the SHA1 in build scripts.

Comment: Does it shows if you try just `security find-identity` ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! How stupid of me. It's a long list to parse, but should be easy.
I ended up with this for now:

$ security find-identity | grep $TEAMID | grep Installer: | awk '{ print $2 }' | uniq |tail -1

The valid entries are always in the second group.

Comment: This is my results: